# Power BI : Paginated Visual from Visualization Throwing Unauthorized Error 401 when being Selected

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

We have developed a page where user can upload a power bi report (pbix) as well as RDL Report in direct query mode. We are using service principle to get power bi client and then perform different operation with the report in workspace.
There is a Preview Section in page where user can see report preview ,For previewing we are using Iframe div container popup ,when user clicks on preview button we are hitting a class with tokenrequestparamater and getting token response back and setting our embedconfig (have added some piece of code for better understanding).

Now the Requirement is user want to see RDL Report within PBIX Report. I know We have paginated report visualization feature from microsoft within pbix report where user can select and click on connect to report but seems when I do in my application ,when I select I am getting below unauthorized error in console, can someone help me regarding resolution. I want to see list of rdl reports in my Iframe when user select paginated report visual feature and click on connect to report like in power bi app service or desktop

Basically I see two Error in console.

1. The first Error when i hit preview ,the report loaded fine but I get this error in console.
2. The second error when I select paginated report visual feature.

   ```
   Error 1: 

   wabi-europe-north-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/tenantsettings/properties 401 (Unauthorized)


    Error 2:

    wabi-europe-north-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/rdlreports 401 (Unauthorized) visual
   ```

   Token Generation:

   ```
     var RequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: accLvl, allowSaveAs: allowSaveAs);

    var tokenResponse = powerbiclient.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(groupID, reportID, RequestParameters );

                        var Config = new EmbedConfig()
                        {
                            EmbedToken = tokenResponse,
                            EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
                            Id = reportIDToString(),
                            ItemType = "xxx",
                            Name = report.Name.Replace(identifier,""),
                            DisplayName = "XX",
                            Description =  "XX",
                            PageName = "XX",
                            EditingAllowed = allowEditing
                        };
   ```

Comment: @vvvv4d  can you help on this

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error means that there’s no permission to access the resource.

Could you please ensure the following:

1. Make sure your service principal has the necessary permissions to access the resources. You can do this by going to the Azure portal, navigating to the Azure Active Directory section, and checking the permissions of your service principal.
2. Ensure that the token you're using is valid and has the necessary scopes to access the resources.
3. Make sure that the RDL report you're trying to access is in the same workspace as the PBIX report and that it's accessible to the service principal.
4. Ensure that your code is correctly generating the token and setting the embed configuration. You might want to try hardcoding some values to see if the issue is with the token generation or the embed configuration.

If this does not help please share the code snapshot of how the token is being fetched.

Please follow this Microsoft Community forum discussion for more details:
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Paginated-Visual-from-Visualization-Throwing/td-p/3516941

Comment: Thats the Same me bro who posted:
Let me explain in more simple way what I want:

1) I believe you would have seen paginated visual feature to connect RDL (Paginated Report) within PBIX Report.
 we can select in any page and connect RDL Reports present in that workspace ,you can check from Power BI Desktop or service.

I posted remaining part in continuous comment.

Comment: 2) we want to achieve the same thing in our application , in our application we have a button to preview report and that preview we are showing
in Iframe ,all the visualization and filters are coming in Iframe but when I select paginated visual I get the Error which I posted above.
The token which we are generating is for that specific report preview and I believe we cannot see all RDL Reports with a particular report token.
I want to know is it even possible to implement similar behaviour what we have in desktop or app service in Iframe ,if yes ,what and how we can do